# How to pass values from html element to a form field django

Tags: html, django, forms, django-1.6

I've a specific html input element that shows a calendar, it is possible to add this element to my form and be validated? i exclude the model field in my form, so when i render not be used in the form fields

```
class AddVisionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Visions
        exclude = ('init_date',
                   )
```

My approach is to pass the post to the save method in the form: `form.save(request.POST)` and save the value to the instance:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = super(AddVisionForm, self).save(commit=False)
    post = args[0]
    instance.init_date = post['init_date']
    instance.save()
```

But this is causing that if a user put other values than the required date format crash the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Meta widgets in the form class to customize your html inputs

For example

```
class AddVisionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Visions
        widgets = {
            'init_date': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'date-calendar'}),
        }
```

You can handle the input with the selector '.date-calendar' and transform that input into a calendar with your preferred javascript function, like jquery-ui calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Instead exclude your init_date model field, you can change the widget of the init_date (probably a hidden input) and populate it using javascript:

```
class AddVisionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Visions
        widgets = {'init_date': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

And you can take approach from the field validation process.